# How to redirect artisan tinker output?

Tags: php, bash, laravel, laravel-artisan

I make large object using the artisan tinker console.
Method output returned from this object does not fit entirely in Artisan Tinker console. I'd like to save it to the file. But how? I'm using linux.

Comment: You can always use the logger within tinker `Log::info('object', $yourLargeObject);`

Answer (score 9):

Try this from the Linux/MAC OSX command line:

```
php artisan tinker | tee /tmp/tinker.out
```

Your output should be in `/tmp/tinker.out` when you are done.

Answer (score 1):

I found your question whilst looking for an answer to this for myself, doing some ad-hoc reporting through an external API tool (QuickBooks Online in this case).

Looking at the docs for Laravel 5.8 the most straight forward way to write to a file is using laravel's storage engine.

**Step 1**

Make sure you have a storage driver activated. This is done in `/config/filesystems.php` I've used `local` as I will deactivate it again once my reporting is done.

**Step 2**

If you're using a class or method you can import storage, otherwise just call the storage module in tinker.

I'm using `json_encode()` with `JSON_PRETTY_PRINT` to make my data easy to read:

This example worked for me:

```php
Storage::disk('local')->put('customer_data.json', json_encode((array) $result, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));
```

**References:**

Lararacasts Q: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/how-to-write-texts-to-file-in-laravel?page=1

File System Docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/filesystem

Answer (score 1):

Storage Facade is great, but configuring shiz sucks....  Just use php native function `file_put_contents()` and write wherever you have permission on the server (/tmp/ works great).

```
$object = mySweetMethodThatRetrievesAwesomelyLargeObject();
file_put_contents('/tmp/my-large-object.obj', json_encode($object, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));
```